# Unable to install SciPy

Tags: command-line, python, dependencies

I need to use the module skimage, which calls the module SciPy (I need to find contours)

```
import numpy
from sys import argv
from PIL import Image
from skimage import measure

# Inicialization
spritesToFind = argv[1]
spriteSize = argv[2]
sheet = Image.open(argv[3])
sheet.verify()

# To grayscale, so contour finding is awesome
grayscale = sheet.convert('L')

# Let numpy do the heavy lifting for converting pixels to pure black or white
data = np.asarray(grayscale).copy()

# Find the contours we need
contours = measure.find_contours(r_grey, 0.8)

# Now we put it back in PIL land
sprite = Image.fromarray(data)
sprite.save(str(Counter), "PNG")
```

I set upon an epic 5 hour journey to figure out to how solve the problem which is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "algo.py", line 4, in <module>
from skimage import measure
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scikit_image-0.9.3-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/skimage/measure/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from ._regionprops import regionprops, perimeter
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scikit_image-0.9.3-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/skimage/measure/_regionprops.py", line 5, in <module>
from scipy import ndimage
ImportError: No module named scipy
```

So I figured I had to install SciPy. I began with `pip` and `easy_install`, couldn't get the thing to work. I downloaded both numpy and scipy tarballs and configured them, but scipy required libraries, which I had, just newer versions, but it didn't want them, even though I pointed them at it. Next thing I needed was gfortran, which I couldn't install because none of the libraries would work( there is a link of gfortran on linuxmint.community but you can't reach it because atpurl says the package is virtual). I tried everything. Can you give me some help? All I want is SciPy to work.

SciPy:

```
Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
the BLAS environment variable.
```

Comment: What distro are you using? Also what version of Python is this?

Comment: Try installing the module via your distros package manager rather than try and install it using pip/easy_install.

Comment: As you clearly are unused to the `pip` and `easy-install` commands for installing python modules (there are no such things as pips/easy-installs), I recommend you follow slm's advice. Getting the different versions of python modules and the non-python libraries they build upon in sync for complex applications can be difficult. Even for someone well versed in using these commands including installing module versioning. It is also possible to break your installation if you replace a needed python module with a broken update unless you use `virtualenv`.

Comment: Please do not deface your posts.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than try to install this module yourself I'd recommend just using it from your distributions repository. I found this module available, so this command should install it for you.

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-scipy
```

If you're going to be doing a fair amount of Python development I'd encourage you to setup your own dedicated instance of Python rather than depend on the one provided by the distribution. True you can use this version, and probably not have too many issues doing so, but when you start to have to install a lot of dependencies (libraries/modules) it can become problematic to do so.

I wrote up detailed notes on how to do this for Python in this U&L Q&A titled: [Upgrading Python 2.6. libpython2.6.so.1.0 missing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92116/upgrading-python-2-6-libpython2-6-so-1-0-missing/92118#92118).

Comment: Try this command then: `apt-cache search scipy`. This package is in the official Ubuntu repositories, I know Mint derives from that distro, not sure how they mix the repositories though.

Comment: @EcoGiko - EXCELLENT! Glad this helped you out. Please mark this as accepted so that others know your issue's been resolved.